# Excel condtional formatting - multipile conditions and search references

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would be very grateful for help with this conditional formatting problem as I'm terrible with excel but learning.

I have a large data set which I want to count specific OPCS codes (Classification of Interventions and Procedures).  The issue is, that in some rows there are multiple OPCS codes that I am searching for and I need to find these rows and then manually decide which is most appropriate so figured highlighting the offending rows would be best.

I previously did this manually by using a simple conditional formatting formula to highlight all the OPCS codes I was interested in, then just scrolled down and made changes. However now I have ~8000 rows which makes this prone to error.

Is it possible for a conditional formatting formula to highlight rows which contains multiple OPCS codes that I am searching for? For reference columns I-U contain the OPCS codes and my lookup OPCS codes I am searching for are in a separate table.

It may be that conditional formatting can't be used for this so alternatives solutions would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

[Spreadsheet image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqXGy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is too complicated to do with a single formula. However, if you are willing to additional 13 columns to your table, can you get the info you need. Let's say you put the first formula in AI2 and fill it across to AU2 and then down to all rows:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(I2,$H2:H2,0)),IFERROR(MATCH(I2,TableOfInterestedCodes[OPCS Code Field Name],0),""),"")

This will display only the unique values of any OPCS codes that you are interested in. Now you can apply the conditional formatting formula as follows:

=COUNT($AI2:$AU2)>1

Answer (score 0):

Select the area to be formatted and use the formula shown below (suitably adjusted to your actual layout)

[image]